# How to implement JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC client from other WebAPI project

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I created a project based on clean architecture in ASP.NET Core and the result is ASP.NET Core Web API project and this project has an endpoint called signing which takes username and password and then returns a JWT token, now I want to use this JWT token in another ASP.NET Core MVC project to authorize users.

Imagine I have some controllers with some actions with `Authorize` attributes. How can I config my ASP.NET Core MVC project to use this token to authorize users?

Comment: write a custom interceptor to varify the token in the request?

Comment: @TinyWang Yeah you are right but I didn't know how to do this, actually, I knew but It didn't work which was a miss-spelling problem. I will record a video tutorial about this issue on youtube (That was interesting for me).

Comment: then maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#action-filters) will help you. Thank you for your reply.